# Rails - activerecord find using has_many relationship and conditions on the "many" side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many, conditional-statements

I'm a complete amateur and I'm sure this is easy...but I'm stuck.

I have a simple situation, I have a table of "activities", each activity can have many "workflows" or statuses leading up to an eventual completion, I need to perform an activerecord find in a controller such that I end up with the activities that do not have any workflows with a status field containing "COMPLETED"

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workflows

class Workflow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :activity
```

In the controller:

```
Activity.all(:include => :workflows, :conditions => workflows.status != 'COMPLETED')
```

This is working to a degree, but instead of giving me only activites that do not have any workflows with status "COMPLETED", I'm getting results that include activites with a COMPLETED workflow as long as that activity also has other, non-COMPLETED workflows...hope this makes sense.

Bottom line, how can I get back the activities whose workflows, no matter how many there may be, do not include status "COMPLETED:?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to see the generated sql statement by using `.to_sql`?

I guess the following should work:

```
Activity.all(:include => :workflows, :joins => :workflows, :conditions => "workflows.status != COMPLETED")
```

(You are using rails 2 finder syntax, so I guess you are not using rails 3, right?)

====== UPDATED ======

```
Activity.all(:include => :workflows, :conditions => "workflows.status != 'COMPLETED'")
```

It seems like rails 2 will do a outer join for `:include`, so no need to use `:joins` anymore.

Also, the `COMPLETED` should be quoted by `'`.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: You are correct, I'm using rails 2...is it true that 'to_sql' is only in rails 3?  I couldn't get it to work...I tried your suggested code, but I get a mysql error complaining about non-unique table or aliases referring to workflows...

Comment: Oh, didn't know that to_sql is in rails 3 only. Maybe you could check the generated sql in the log file. I'm now creating a test project to reconstruct your problem.